# Minimum resolution - how to achieve in CSS? (scroll bars)

Tags: css, resize, resolution

I don't want the users on my webpage to be able to resize the window and therefore mess up the layout of the page.

I know I can't stop them from resizing, but I can at least have scroll bars appear when the window reaches a certain minimum size (as happens right here at Stackoverflow).

How can this be done using CSS?

Comment: It's just a `min-width` and a `min-height` thing :)

Answer (score 0):

Yes. You need to use `min-width` CSS property to achieve what you are looking for.

**For Instance,**

```
html,body{
overflow-x: auto;
min-width:xxpx; /* enter a pixel value that distorts the layout on resize */
}
```

***PS:** xxpx is an illustrative value. Use the value that is ideal for your resolution.*